# Append record with binary value

Tags: mainframe, syncsort

I have a file with FB length=80. I want to append fixed value numeric `1` at position 81, if value at position 80=`'Y'`

This appended value is supposed to be `S9(9) BINARY` when viewed from a copybook.

The appended field will be used in `SUM FIELDS` in a separate step.

How do I code the `SORT SYSIN` card ?

Answer (score 0):

```
OPTION COPY
INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=(80,1,CH,EQ,C'Y'),OVERLAY=(81:+1,TO=BI,LENGTH=2))
```

There is no need for this to be separate from you step with SUM in. Obviously you'd not use the OPTION COPY.

If you are SUMming records other than Y in Col 80, you'll need a IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT to set everything to zero first.

Since this is a Mainframe task, you'd have got an earlier response if you'd used that Tag.